# How do I reflect Stock Profit and Dividend in New York State Tax 2020

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, state-income-tax, new-york

Please help me

1. I googled how to reflect stock profit and dividends for New York State tax, but it led me to New York State tax website I was unable to understand.
2. Few days ago I called New York State tax. The gentleman put me on hold. When he returned, he said his Supervisor said I should ask IRS.
3. Today I called New York State tax. The gentleman put me on hold. When he returned, he said I should report it to the IRS taxes, then New York will be informed.

I am really confused. Before I call IRS or anyone else, can you tell me what I am overlooking? Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many state income tax forms, New York's [IT-201](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/it/it201.pdf) relies heavily on your federal tax return. Lines 3 and 7 of this form deal with dividends and capital gains.

You may wish to use tax software to make things easier. New York has some "Free File" software partners listed [here](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/efile/default.htm).